# recyclerview: UI freezes for some seconds when initially loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which loads appr. 200 items. When opening the activity with the recyclerview, for 2 - 3 seconds ui freezes (I can't scroll). After that, I can scroll normally.

Is there an event that is triggered when recyclerview is fully loaded? So I can show a loader until scrolling is enabled? Or other solution to prevent UI is freezing?

Comment: Where does those 200 comes from?

Comment: some code would be helpful

Comment: I have the same issue..any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try attaching a Pre Draw listener to your recycler view. This should work.

```
recycler.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                recycler.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                // Your code here

                return true;
            }
        });
```